# How retrieve key value form jason in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have column called genres, has

```
[
    { "id": 28, "name": "Action" }, 
    { "id": 12, "name": "Adventure" }, 
    { "id": 14, "name": "Fantasy" }, 
    { "id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction" }
]
```

This is only one row, I have 4800 rows.

I want retrieve only name of movies from json format but in new data frame. I think we have to use loop.

I want this output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvkpx.png)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read in key-value pair from a json file as a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065450/how-to-read-in-key-value-pair-from-a-json-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your question correctly. Assume that you have the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [4, 5, 6],
        "b": [7, 8, 9],
        "c": [
            {"x": 1, "y": 2},
            {"x": 3, "y": 4},
            {"x": 5, "y": 6}
        ]
    },
)
```

Then, using `df.c.map(lambda v: v["x"])` returns as a `pandas.Series` the values that correspond to the `x` keys in the dictionaries in the column `c`.

NB: And *don't* use loops for something like that. Check out the concept of vectorization.

Comment: `Series.map` is a loop… you can't vectorize operation on python objects.

Comment: @mozway do you have a reference to this statement?

Comment: Do you have a reference that `map` is vectorized? ;) You can check the source, although the code is a bit cryptic (you have to follow several files, the magic happens in `pandas/core/algorithms.py`)

Comment: i got this error. string indices must be integers

Comment: I cannot know why. Your question must be more focused and with more details on your code.